# shim error: docker-runc not installed on system

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am new to Docker and encountering an odd issue `/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: shim error: docker-runc not installed on system.`. command that I am running is `docker build /path to docker file/`. But when I tried to run docker-runc it can able to pop up its version as `VERSION:
   1.0.0-rc2
spec: 1.0.0-rc2-dev`. Also docker version is 1.13.1, build 774336d/1.13.1. Any help would be appreciated.

Attached is the docker info below.

Adding docker info`Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: rootvg-docker--pool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file:
 Metadata file:
 Data Space Used: 20.45 MB
 Data Space Total: 20.72 GB
 Data Space Available: 20.7 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 53.25 kB
 Metadata Space Total: 109.1 MB
 Metadata Space Available: 109 MB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 2.071 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.140-RHEL7 (2017-05-03)
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Authorization: rhel-push-plugin
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: docker-runc runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version:  (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: N/A (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
Operating System: RHEV
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 19.44 GiB
Name: tdctvjnkcit01
ID: BOQP:ENIT:7N7J:5EW6:OOVI:6AHX:HUVI:Y6FU:NO7B:TAJI:LDJY:AJBV
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://registry.access.redhat.com/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registry Mirrors:
 https://docker-dev.xxxx.com
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries: registry.access.redhat.com (secure), docker.io (secure)`

Comment: Add your `docker info` output. I've found sometimes restarts help these strange errors

Comment: Are you building docker from source?

Comment: @stacksonstacks